# Mimicking Java setRequestProperty with CURL for RESTful Authentication

Tags: java, rest, authentication, curl, restful-authentication

I do not know Java and I haven't had success with Google or trial and error testing...

How would I write this with just using CURL on the command line for a RESTful API authentication?  (a php or perl solution would also be okay)

This code is from documentation but I don't plan on using Java and need to translate it.

```java
URL url = new URL("http://www.thingsandstuff.com/resfulness/post");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// i don't know if this is relevant to my question or not... 
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

// this is what i think might be the problem... 
String userNamePassword = "myusername:mypassword";
userNamePassword =
      new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(userNamePassword
      .getBytes()));

conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", userNamePassword);
```

I always get a 401 unauthorized error.

I've been just playing with the header argument `-H`.  I don't know if what I am doing is not working because I am truly not doing the authentication right or if it is something else.  The data is xml and I am testing with something very simple/straightforward.  I am assuming that even if my data/xml/post is incorrect, it would be returning an error instead of an unauthorized.

```bsh
# bXl1c2VybmFtZTpteXBhc3N3b3Jk == myusername:mypassword base64 encoded.... 

curl -H "bXl1c2VybmFtZTpteXBhc3N3b3Jk" -d "<datums>" -X POST http://www.thingsandstuff/restfulness/post 
curl -H "bXl1c2VybmFtZTpteXBhc3N3b3Jk" -d "<datums>" -X POST  http://www.thingsandstuff/restfulness/post 

# and like this... with encoded things and not encoded things... 

curl -d "<datums>" -X POST  http://user:password@www.thingsandstuff.com/restfulness/post 
curl -u user:password -d "<datums>" -X POST  http://www.thingsandstuff.com/restfulness/post
```

And for all three, I've tried encoding just the password, both together, both separately, neither... And I'm sure it doesn't help that my username does have a `\` and the password does end in an `!` but I think, when I'm not encoding them, I am escaping properly.

And the [curl man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) says that `-d` `will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so that means I don't need to pass an additional header saying the content-type, right?  Basically... I only partially know what I'm doing and it doesn't work and there are too many things I don't know about enough to isolate my issue or probably even correct it (yes, just enough to be dangerous).

Comment: maybe... I need to do both?  `-u` and `-H`?  Is that ever a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this is what I ended up with...

```bash
curl -H "Authorization:dXNlclxuYW1lOnBhc3N3b3JkIQ==" -X POST -d 'data=%3C%3Fxml+version....' http://www.stuffandthings.com:8080/restfulness/post
```

So... `username:password` is base 64 encoded together.  The data is encoded by ISO/IEC 8859-1 and prefixed with "data=" this particular set restful service.

I ended up putting it in PHP just because it was easier to test continuously that way.  And this is what ended up working for that...

```php
$user     = 'user\\name';
$pass     = 'password!';  
$userpass =  base64_encode($user.':'.$pass);
$url      = 'http://www.thingsandstuff.com:8080/restfulness/post';  

if (($handle = fopen("foo.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    { 
        list($thing1,$thing2) = $data;

        $xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>
        <entry xmlns=\"http://purl.org/atom/ns#\"> 
            <xml data goes here>
                <ns:thing1>$param1</ns:thing1>
                <ns:thing2>$param2</ns:thing2>
            </xml data goes here>
        </entry>";

        $datums = 'data='.utf8_decode($xml);
        $result = do_curl($url,$datums); 

        // not actually using the response at this
        // point... just running through everything 
        var_dump($result); 
    }
    fclose($handle);
} 

function do_curl($url, $data) {  
    global $userpass, $user, $pass; 

    $ch = curl_init(); 

    $header = array('Authorization:'.$userpass,
                    'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Content-Length:'.strlen($data)); 

    // this line was the last thing to be added before it worked
    // i didn't try it again, removing the authentication in $header
    // to see if this was the only thing actually needed...  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.':'.$pass); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $result = curl_exec($ch); 

    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $hout   = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);

    //echo "\n"; var_dump($hout); echo "\n"; 

    curl_close($ch); 

    return array('status'=>$status, 'result'=>$result);  
}
```

And If I `var_dump($hout)` from the `do_curl` function... the header actually sent was:

```bash
POST /resfulness/post HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic dXNlclxuYW1lOnBhc3N3b3JkIQ==
Host: www.thingsandstuff.com:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 409
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
        <entry xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#"> 
            <xml data goes here>
                <ns:thing1>value1</ns:thing1>
                <ns:thing2>value2</ns:thing2>
            </xml data goes here>
        </entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the 401 is the Authorization header needs a scheme prefix, in your case `Basic`

So currently you are sending

```
Authorization: <base64(username:password)>
```

But the web server expects

```
Authorization: Basic <base64(username:password)>
```

as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

this change should work:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + userNamePassword);
```

Comment: I'm not using Java so I can't use `conn.setRequestProperty`